# Aggregate Python DF based on column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a big dataframe (approximately 35 columns), where 1 column - `concat_strs` is a concatenation of 8 columns in the dataframe. This is used to detect duplicates. What I want to do is to aggregate rows, where `concat_strs` has the same value, on columns `val, abs_val, price, abs_price` (using sum).

I have done the following:

```
agg_attributes = {'val': 'sum', 'abs_val': 'sum', 'price': 'sum', 'abs_price': 'sum'}
final_df= df.groupby('concat_strs', as_index=False).aggregate(agg_attributes)
```

But, when I look at final_df, I notice 2 issues:

- Other columns are removed, so I have only 5 columns. I have tried to do `final_df.reindex(columns=df.columns)`, but then all of the other columns are `NaN`
- The number of rows in the `final_df` remains the same as in the `df` (ca. 300k rows). However, it should be reduced (checked manually)

The question is - what is done wrong and is there any improvement suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You groupby `concat_strs`, so only `concat_strs` and the columns in `agg_attributes` is kept, because `groupby` operation, pandas does not know what to do with other columns.

You can include all columns with `first` agg to keep the first value of that column (if duplicated), or `last` etc.. depends on what you need.

Also this way to dedup I bet it a good operation, can you simply drop all the duplicates?

You dont need to `concat_strs` too, as `groupby` support input in a list of column to group on

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly. but you can try this?

```
final_df = df.groupby(['concat_strs']).sum()
```